# How do I use a block to display search results?

Tags: search, block-editor

We are using the search gutenberg block on a new gutenberg site for our search form, but can't figure out which block to use on the search results page to display the search results?

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/13583

[image: Using This Form]

Step 1 in this image is easy, can't figure out the results display portion.  which block to use on the the gutenberg block template with the slug search to display the search results?  We can get a block template to render when any search is executed but are at a loss which block to display the results grid/list based on that search query.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the query loop block.

In that block's sidebar, make sure that you have "Inherit query from template" toggled on.

(Previous edit, in early 2020, stated that displaying search results as a block was not yet possible)

Comment: i see. thanks.

we are building a number of pure gutenberg only sites right now, using the block wp_template to theme template mapping so that the only php template file we have is a functions file, no template files other than that, everything else is pure blocks and block templates.

we have every feature working on all the sites so far using only blocks except search results. looks like we'll have to write a custom block for that one last piece. pure gutenberg sites are soooo close, this is the last piece. 